# Is it possible to disabled the reflection based destructurer in Serilog.Exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, logging, serilog, serilog-exceptions

The package [`Serilog.Exceptions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Exceptions/) is nice for logging exceptions. It has a large list of supported exception types.

e.g. the current setup:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Currently it falls back to a "reflection based destructurer" if no destructurer is found for a exception type.

Because of performance, but more important of predictability, we would like to disable the reflection fallback.

I tried configuring this with `DestructuringOptions`, e.g. disable some of the default destructors or setting the DestructuringDepth to `0`.

Unfortunately, those options won't work:

- the `ReflectionBasedDestructurer` isn't in the default destructor list
- setting `DestructuringDepth` to `0` isn't allowed (exception)

Any idea how to configure Serilog.Exceptions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been added to Serilog.Exceptions 5.4.0, see [changelog](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/releases/tag/5.4.0). There is a new method `WithoutReflectionBasedDestructurer`.

### Usage

#### Helper class

```cs
public static class LoggerEnrichmentConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration WithExceptionDetailsWithoutReflection(
        this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration loggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        if (loggerEnrichmentConfiguration is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerEnrichmentConfiguration));
        }
        var options = new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
            .WithDefaultDestructurers()
            .WithoutReflectionBasedDestructurer() //new in 5.4.0!
            .WithIgnoreStackTraceAndTargetSiteExceptionFilter();
        var logEventEnricher = new ExceptionEnricher(options);
        return loggerEnrichmentConfiguration.With(logEventEnricher);
    }
}
```

#### Config

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetailsWithoutReflection()
                .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option you have is to implement your own `ExceptionDecostructor`, something like this:

```
 public class FallbackExceptionDestructurer : ExceptionDestructurer
 {
        public override Type[] TargetTypes => new[]
        {
            typeof(Exception),
        };

        public override void Destructure(
            Exception exception,
            IExceptionPropertiesBag propertiesBag,
            Func<Exception, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>> destructureException)
        {
            base.Destructure(exception, propertiesBag, destructureException);
        }
 }
```

This way you will keep all the available destructurers and the reflection based will be ignored because `FallbackExceptionDestructurer` will cover all unknown exceptions due to this code:

```
public override Type[] TargetTypes => new[]
{
  typeof(Exception),
};
```

This is how you are registering destructurers

```
.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
    .WithDefaultDestructurers()
    .WithDestructurers(new[] { new FallbackExceptionDestructurer () }))
```

If you check the source code  of the [ExceptionDestructurer.Decostruct(...)](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions/blob/master/Source/Serilog.Exceptions/Destructurers/ExceptionDestructurer.cs#L235) it does not use any reflection - only well known properties from the Exception type.